# Removing process.env.NODE_ENV with browserify/envify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, browserify

So I am using ReactJS through NPM and Browserify however I am trying to figure out how to build it in production mode like the readme says but it does not seems to be working.  I have this code to setup the browserify:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var envify = require('envify/custom');
var debug = false;
```

...

```
var libraries = browserify({
  debug: debug
}).transform(envify({
  _: 'purge',
  NODE_ENV: debug ? 'development' : 'production'
}));

gulpConfig.tasks.browserify.transformers.forEach(function(transform) {
  libraries.transform(transform);
});

gulpConfig.tasks.browserify.libraries.forEach(function(metaData) {
  if(metaData.path) {
    libraries.require(metaData.path, {
      expose: metaData.name
    });
  } else {
    libraries.require(metaData.name);
  }
});

var libraryStream = libraries.bundle()
.on('error', function(err){
  var message;

  if(err.description)
    message = 'browserify error: ' + err.description + ' when parsing ' + err.fileName + ' | Line ' + err.lineNumber + ', Column ' + err.column;
  else {
    message = err.message;
  }

  gutil.log(gutil.colors.red(message));

  this.emit('end');
})
.pipe(source('libraries.js'));

libraryStream.pipe(gulp.dest(gulpConfig.buildPath));
```

However when I looked at the compiled code, I see a bunch of this:

```
if ("production" !== process.env.NODE_ENV) {
```

I though it should compile to:

```
if ("production" !== "production") {
```

Which could then be automatically removed by tools like UglifyJS2.  Am I setting Envify up wrong? or something.

Comment: You don't appear to have given browserify an entry point for your code - it should be the first argument to `browserify()` or an `entries` prop in the options object you're passing.

Comment: I only added what I though was relevant code but I have updated with full browserify code for building my libraries.js file.  Note there is no entry point for the bundle since it just contains the core libraries, file that don't change very often, so I manually add them with `require()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

React already configures `envify` automatically. It will pick up the environment that the build script itself is running in. You'd generally set `NODE_ENV` before running your actual build scripts, e.g.

```
NODE_ENV=production gulp build
```

Or even better, you'd have added your build step to the `"scripts"` block in your `package.json`, so then you can just do

```
npm run --production build
```

Comment: you can also set `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'` in your gulp script if you have separate production and development tasks.  It's mostly personal preference which way you do it.

Answer (score 2):

simply change to

```
var libraries = browserify({
  debug: debug
}).transform(envify({
  _: 'purge',
  NODE_ENV: debug ? 'development' : 'production'
}), {
  global: true
});
```